# How can I prevent a positional argument from being expanded into keyword arguments?

Tags: ruby, arguments, ruby-2.0, keyword-argument

I'd like to have a method that accepts a hash and an optional keyword argument. I tried defining a method like this:

```
def foo_of_thing_plus_amount(thing, amount: 10)
  thing[:foo] + amount
end
```

When I invoke this method with the keyword argument, it works as I expect:

```
my_thing = {foo: 1, bar: 2}
foo_of_thing_plus_amount(my_thing, amount: 20) # => 21
```

When I leave out the keyword argument, however, the hash gets eaten:

```
foo_of_thing_plus_amount(my_thing) # => ArgumentError: unknown keywords: foo, bar
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Is there such a thing as an anti-splat?

Comment: Thanks. At least I know a workaround now: use the keyword parameter every time. Pretty annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in Ruby 2.0.0-p247, see [this issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8040).

Comment: The linked issue mentions backporting. What does that mean to me, practically? Can I update my 2.0.0-p247 version of ruby somehow? Or does it mean whatever release they issued of 2.0.0-pX after this would have the fix?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
def foo_of_thing_plus_amount(thing, opt={amount: 10})
  thing[:foo] + opt[:amount]
end

my_thing = {foo: 1, bar: 2}   # {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
foo_of_thing_plus_amount(my_thing, amount: 20)   # 21
foo_of_thing_plus_amount(my_thing)   # 11
```

?

Comment: This works for the OP's hypothetical example. But if the original method definition included multiple optional keyword arguments, your example line (that results in 21) would remove them in the received `opt` argument, because only the `amount` key would be passed. As it is, my current use case IS the hypothetical example, so this helps.